# python and string from list as parameter

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python script that reads lines of strings from a file and executes a bash-shell command with each line as parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

lines = [line.strip() for line in open('/tmp/i586rpm.txt')]
for rpm in lines:
    try:
        s = os.system("rpm -qip") % lines

    except Exception:
        print "Something wrong"
```

But I always get an error. I think that there is something wrong with `% lines`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you're not building the command string properly. Try:

```
s = os.system("rpm -qip \"%s\"" % rpm)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that could be improved:

- Uses `os.system` instead of `subprocess.Popen` (for more information, please have look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system))
- Iterates over lines, but it doesn't use the iteration variable (`rpm`)
- Attemps to format the output string from `os.system` with `lines` as a parameter.

My advice is to use this code:

```
for line in lines:
    p = subprocess.Popen('rpm -qip {0}'.format(line),
                         shell=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: This answer is by far better than unwind's.

Comment: Great.But how i can output rpm -qip {0} into directly into shell or file?

Comment: @user413036 I'm not sure what do you mean. If the problem is regarding `{0}`, note that `'{0}'.format(line)` is equivalent to `'%s' % line`.

Comment: @user413036 You probably don't want to output it into a shell, you just wand to execute it. And that's what the call above for. Maybe even better `p = subprocess.Popen(['rpm', '-qip', '{0}'.format(line)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` - the shell is not needed here.

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
for rpm in lines:
    s = os.system("rpm -qip") % lines
```

do this

```
for rpm in lines:
    s = os.system('rpm -qip "%s"' % rpm)
```

**EDIT** correct the code

Comment: That still won't work as you put the % rpm outside of the os.system call. `s = os.system('rpm -qip "%s"' % rpm)`